# How can I get the value of a lookup field by javascript in Microsoft dynamics crm 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am trying to get a lookup field value and set the value into another field ('Name' field for example) by Javascript in Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
How can I do it?

Comment: What pages???
You want change javascript default in pages?

Comment: No, I dont want to change default of MS Dynamics CRM. I just want to add new functionality to my form as I save the form, some of fields contents concatenate in name field of form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it on docs.microsoft. To do this, first you should know about Document Object Model in Dynamics CRM which is called "Xrm":

```
var lookupValue=Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('new_account').getValue()[0].name;
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_name").setValue("Your Account Name is:"+lookupValue);
```

You can use it as a function and call it on save (OnSave) event of Microsoft dynamics CRM Form.

Comment: Xrm.Page is deprecated. There are updated ways of retrieving the attribute value; however, your question does not have enough detail. Is this a form library?

Comment: I didn't see anything about deprecation of Xrm.Page, it mentioned in docs.Microsoft as a model. Can you help me about updated ways???

Comment: Here is the list of deprecated methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming#some-client-apis-are-deprecated

Comment: Are you trying to do something in a form library?

Comment: Yes, I use it in a form library.

Answer (score 4):

To use the new (CRM 365) methods you need to do two things:

When you write your form library, your function must include a parameter. This is set by CRM when it calls your function. In my example here, the parameter name is `executionContext` but the name does't matter

Once you have this CRM parameter, you can get the **Form Context** which is the new `Xrm.Page` equivalent. See below

```
function onLoad(executionContext)
{
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

  var lookup = formContext.getAttribute("new_account").getValue();
  formContext.getAttribute("new_name").setValue("Your Account Name is:" + lookup[0].name);
}
```

Secondly, when you register your form library, you must pass the Execution Context. This is what tells CRM that your form library method has the `executionContext` parameter that must be set

[image: Pass execution context]

Comment: Thank you for your answer...i'll check it.